# How to write a complex logical condition correctly?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have 2 tables in Access: FACULTY and SGROUP.

FACULTY:

[image: FACULTY]

SGROUP:

[image: SGROUP]

I need to output SGROUP.GrpNo and FACULTY.FacNo under one condition ...

```
IIF (FACULTY.Fund> 20000 AND SGROUP.Rating> 10) OR (faculty group from building 6 AND SGROUP.Rating <70) OR (faculty group from building 5 AND SGROUP.Rating> 40)
```

I understand what they want from me, but I absolutely do not understand how a complex condition can be built on sql to solve this problem.

P.S: The rest of the database tables.

DEPARTMENT:

[image: DEPARTMENT]

TEACHER:

[image: TEACHER]

SUBJECT:

[image: SUBJECT]

ROOM:

[image: ROOM]

LECTURE:

[image: LECTURE]

Comment: what is the logical relation between the tables?

Comment: @asi, essentially, no connection. It also terribly confuses me, but such a task.
We cannot change the tables, as far as I understand, according to the condition of the problem.

Comment: @asi, I can supplement the question and show 4 more tables. Maybe I don't understand something? But it seems to me that you need to work with these tables.

Comment: please add what you have

Comment: @asi, done. There are no more tables in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go my friend:

```
select 
    *
from 
    lecture l
inner join
    teacher t on t.tchno = l.tchno
inner join 
    department d on d.depno = t.depno
inner join 
    faculty f on f.facno = d.facno
inner join 
    sgroup sg on sg.groupno = l.sbjno
inner join 
    room r on r.roomno = l.roomno
where     
    (f.Fund> 20000 AND sg.Rating> 10) OR 
    (r.Building = 6 AND sg.Rating <70) OR 
    (r.Building 5 AND sg.Rating> 40)
```